# In Angular 14 and PrimeNG, how do I set the value of a radio button to be the key of an enum?

Tags: typescript, enums, radio-button, primeng, angular14

I'm using Angular 14.  I have defined this enum ...

```
export enum Color {
    RED = 'Red Color',
    BLUE = 'Blue Color'
}
```

I have a PrimeNg radio button where I want to set the value of the radio button to be the key of the enum (e.g. RED), so I tried

```
        <p-radioButton
          #red
          name="color"
          [value]="Color().RED"
          formControlName="color"
        ></p-radioButton>
```

Here is the relevant service code

```
  public Color() {
    return Color;
  }
```

However, the value of the radio button is getting set to "Red Color" and I want the value set to "RED".  What's the proper syntax for making this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-  In your component, declare your enum as follows:

```
readonly colors: typeof Color = Color;
```

2- Create a pipe that retrieves the key of a given enum value:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'enumKey'
})
export class EnumKeyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, enumObject: any): string {
    return Object.keys(enumObject).find((key: string) => enumObject[key] === value) || '';
  }
}
```

3- In your template, use the enumKey pipe to retrieve the key of the enum value:

```
<div class="p-field-radiobutton">
  <p-radioButton name="color" [value]="colors.RED | enumKey: colors" formControlName="color"></p-radioButton>
  <label for="color">RED</label>
</div>
```

By following this approach, you declare the *colors* variable to hold a reference to the `Color` enum, which allows you to access the enum keys in your template. The `enumKey` pipe is used to retrieve the key of the enum value, and it takes the *colors.RED* value and the colors enum as arguments.

Comment: In your pipe, the line "return Object.keys(enumObject).find((key) => enumObject[key] === value);" is generating the Typescript error, "Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'."

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. You can resolve the error by using a type assertion `as string` at the end of the line. I will modify the solution accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Thanks but in the pipe, the "enumObject[key]" is giving the compilation error, "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'."

Comment: I apologize for any confusion caused. I'm sorry I forgot to mention that the `noImplicitAny` compiler option was set to false in my `tsconfig.ts` file. However, it appears that when I changed it to true, it actually caused the error. You were right. Could you please review the updated pipe to confirm that the error has been resolved? @Dave

Comment: Nice work.  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: You're most welcome! It brings me great joy to know that the provided answer has proven helpful to you.